# Three.js load a single .obj model , how to show vertex colors

Tags: colors, three.js, .obj

I am new to Three.js (3D) and have a simple question. I have the following code that will work properly, but I think the result lost their colors because I open the test.obj file whith 3D Buidler(WIN10), there are lots of colors on ther surface of model. why?

The Code

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader()
loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.position.y = 0;
    scene.add( object );                
} );
```

I think it's vertex color, How to show it's vertex color?

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader2()
loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.position.y = 0;
    scene.add( object );                
} );
```

I have tryed OBJLoader2.js , but it doesn't work, need some settings?

The result loaded by Three.js:

[image: The result loaded by Three.js]

The result loaded by 3D Builder:

[image: The result loaded by 3D Builder]

[The obj file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ti23ffs6m0bxs43/test.obj?dl=0)

Comment: You may have to check how the materials are intepreted after being loaded by the `ObjLoader`. And you may have to assign some values to the material.

Comment: Thanks, but  I did nothing  when I opened the .obj file  by 3D Builder,  and there is not a .mtl file , so don't know how to do about this problem

Comment: As I indicated before, the OBJLoader may have lost some materials parameters, and thus, you will have to reassign materials values by code. Can you upload the original texture ?

Comment: I have uploaded the obj file just now(There is only a .obj file and sorry about the file link because I have no enough reputations. TT)

Comment: @sensen Use `OBJLoader2.js`, instead, and you should see the vertex colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it out :
I changed OBJLoader2.js's version to 1.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

use the .mtl file along with the .obj file.

```
var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                }
            };

            var onError = function ( xhr ) { };

            THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

            //Car model
            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setPath( '../materials/car/' );
            mtlLoader.load( 'car.mtl', function( materials ) {

                materials.preload();

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( '../materials/car/' );
                objLoader.load( 'car.obj', carObject, onProgress, onError );

            });

            function carObject(object){
                object.rotation.y = 1.55;
                object.position.z = 105;
                object.position.y = 1.15;

                object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = 0.15;
                    //object.rotation.x = 6.5;
                    //object.position.z = 50;

                scene.add( object );
            }
            //end car model
```

Comment: Thanks,  but there is only a .obj file

Comment: Then look here [link]https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

Comment: Only a .obj file , no pictures, no  .mtl file